# When writing an accompaniment, should the melody appear in the soprano of the accompaniment?

Tags: voice-leading

In a normal harmony exercise you are given the melody on the treble clef and you are supposed to fill in the other voices. When writing an accompaniment however you are given a melody and need to write an accompaniment on a separate grand staff. How does one do this? Are the melody notes the soprano of the accompaniment or can you just write chords that will support the melody without actually needing to include the notes in the accompaniment.

Comment: Perhaps because the accompaniment and the melody are supposed to be realized by different musicians? Normally musicians expect to see only their own part in the staff. These are my guesses, but perhaps it's something that should be clarified by the textbook with the exercise.

Comment: I added a picture. Can you see what I mean? would the accompaniment include the notes of the melody in the soprano? So lets say the B of bar 1. Would that note be the soprano note of the 4 part harmony in the grand staff below?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the instructions for the exercise makes clear that the accompaniment is independent of the melody, and the answer, being specific to this exercise in this textbook, is unlikely to be of future use.

Comment: Armani, as you can see by my previous comment, IMO this isn't a good question for the main site. However, I've posted the answer in the main chat room.

Comment: Ok thanks Aaron. I did change the title because it wasnt correct but whatever you think is best.

Comment: You could certainly turn it into a more general question, but then I suggest removing all references to the textbook exercise. Doing so would still leave @LaurencePayne's answer relevant.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a 'complete the harmony by adding Alto, Tenor and Bass parts' question.  It's 'write a piano part to accompany this melody'.

You COULD start by doubling up the melody in the piano part.  Lots of piano accompaniments do this.  But the question gives a hint that you might choose to be more adventurous than that.  For instance - are you going to treat the first two bars as a sort of fanfare, with just one chord held underneath?  All the melody notes fit one simple chord.  Or are you going to give each note a different harmony?  Or each pair of notes?  Or...  time for YOU to come up with an idea!

If you were playing piano, and the melody was a singer, what could you play to support them?  What are some of the textures you might use - remember, it's a piano part, not a hymn tune.